# How exactly was Kyousuke able to defeat Kengo's father in a kendo match?

Tags: little-busters

In *Little Busters!: Refrain*, we saw exactly how Kyousuke was able to get Masato to fight with only one hand and eventually defeat and befriend him. However, when it comes to how Kengo was recruited into the Little Busters, it wasn't played out in as much detail as Masato's. Specifically, I'm referring to this scene:

[image: What kind of dirty trick is this?]

There's no doubt that Kyousuke had used some dirty tricks on Kengo's father, but I need more explanation on what was Kyousuke holding and what tricks he pulled to overcome my disbelief that a kid could defeat a kendo master in a kendo match, fair or not. Was it ever explained in more details in the visual novel?

Comment: I think the hay-man thing is just a Japanese scarecrow and similar ones have appeared in other shows, which is why it looks familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the anime nor the visual novel shows how exactly Kengo's dad was defeated. However, in the visual novel, Kengo's dad wasn't defeated by Kyousuke alone - he was beaten when Masato, Kyousuke and Rin went up against him at the same time.

[Source1](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13117410548) and [Source2](http://hienkyaku.blog50.fc2.com/blog-entry-3522.html)